# How to split value using character-wise in java

Tags: android, regex

[A-D]?[E-F]?[2-4][0-2] this is my pattern. I need to split like [A-D] in 1 postion, ? in 2 position , [E-F] in 3 position, like this..

Comment: what you have done ?

Comment: @Fasiha if u know that mean pls help.String pattern = "[A-D]?[E-F]?[2-4][0-2]";for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            String a_letter = Character.toString(pattern.charAt(i));
            if (a_letter.contains("[")) {
                Log.d("index", "" + i);
                Log.d("PatternCheck", "" + pattern.substring(i, pattern.length()));
               
            }

Comment: do mean A-D alphabets right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.split(String regex) function

```
String a= "[A-D]\\?[E-F]\\?[2-4][0-2]";
    String splitedString[] = a.split("\\?"); //splitedSring[] = {"[A-D]" ,"[E-F]", "[2-4][0-2]"}
    String[] newsplitedString = new String[ 2*splitedString.length -1];
    for(int i=0 ; i<splitedString.length ; i++){
        newsplitedString[2*i] = splitedString[i];
        if(i != splitedString.length-1)
            newsplitedString[2*i + 1] = "&";
    }
```

Detailed Information about Split() function can be obtained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: no not like that, i already used this one, i need to store in arraylist [A-D], ? , [E-F],..... SO question mark also i need .

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i did in like this for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {String a_letter = Character.toString(pattern.charAt(i));
            if (a_letter.contains("[")) {  ij = i;}
            if (a_letter.contains("]")) {//Log.d("PatternCheck1", "" + pattern.substring(ij, i + 1));splitData.add(pattern.substring(ij, i + 1));}
            if (a_letter.contains("?")) {String ss = String.valueOf(pattern.charAt(i));splitData.add(ss);}}